# JavaFX - Open a url only in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, javafx

JavaFx : Trying to open a specific link using only Internet Explorer. 
Tried this using some of the solutions. Did not work for me.

```
            final Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink("cmd" + " " + "/c" + "start" + " " + "iexplore" + " " + "http://www.google.com");
            application.getHostServices().showDocument(hyperlink.getText());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start iexplore " + url);
```

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, or when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.^_^

Comment: I wasn't able to do that few minutes ago when i tried. It worked now. Hope it helps someone :)